# iOS App Rejected - in-app purchase products have not been submitted for review

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I submitted an app in the AppStore which includes renewable subscriptions

But it was rejected

They give me following clarifications

**Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness**

We are unable to complete the review of your app because one or more of your in-app purchase products have not been submitted for review.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please be sure to take action and submit your in-app purchases and upload a new binary in App Store Connect so we can proceed with our review.

**Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions**

We noticed that your app did not meet all the terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement.

We were unable to find the following required information in your app's binary:

– Title of publication or service
– Length of subscription (time period and content or services provided during each subscription period)
– Price of subscription, and price per unit if appropriate
– A functional link to the Terms of Use (EULA)
– A functional link to the privacy policy

We were unable to find the following required item(s) in your app's metadata:

– A functional link to the Terms of Use (EULA)

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please add this missing information. If the above information is present, please reply to this message in App Store Connect to provide details on where to locate it.

If you are using the standard Apple Terms of Use (EULA), you will need to include a link to the Terms of Use in your App Description. If you are using a custom EULA, add it in App Store Connect.

About Guideline 2.1
I already submitted my app with in auto renewable subscription then why it is showing that one or more of your in-app purchase products have not been submitted for review.

About Guideline 3.1.2
How to meet all the criteria for renew-able subscriptions

Any suggestion or resources how to solve this issues.

Rejection Attachment

[image: Provided by apple]